# Error message "Error in paired || !is.null(y) : invalid 'x' type in 'x || y' "

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Please help me understand why am I getting that error and any way to fix it. Thank you!

```
a<- filter(combine2, NEIGHBORHOOD_NAME=="ASTORIA", YEAR_BUILT>="2009")$SALE_PRICE
b<- filter(combine2, NEIGHBORHOOD_NAME=="CORONA", YEAR_BUILT>="2009")$SALE_PRICE

t.test(a,b, alternative = "greater", mu=0, paired= "false", conf.level = .95)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error is based on the `t.test` where the `paired` takes a logical value i.e. `TRUE/FALSE` instead of a string "false"

```
t.test(a,b, alternative = "greater", mu=0, paired= FALSE, conf.level = .95)
```

i.e. the error is reproducible with

```
t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20), paired = "false")
```

> Error in paired || !is.null(y) : invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'

instead it would be

```
t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))     

#   Welch Two Sample t-test

#data:  1:10 and c(7:20)
#t = -5.4349, df = 21.982, p-value = 1.855e-05
#alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# -11.052802  -4.947198
#sample estimates:
#mean of x mean of y 
#      5.5      13.5
```